# Test Index out of range golang

Tags: arrays, go

Sorry for this noob question, but I'm not sure how I test to see if an element I'm accessing is valid for an array, consider the following contrived code:

```
func main() {
    strings := []string{"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"}
    for i := 0; i<5; i++ {
        if strings[i] {
            fmt.Println(strings[i])
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8QjGadu6Fu

I'm obviously going outside of the bounds, but I'm not sure how I test to prevent the error. I'm used to PHP where I would use an `isset` or `!empty` test, does go have such a thing?

I've browsed other questions and seen the `len` function used, but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Use the `len` function to get the length of a slice.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Go, this is not quite as easy as in PHP - but keep in mind that in PHP it's only easy because "indexed" arrays are actually associative arrays under the hood. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to "punch holes" into arrays by unsetting individual elements.

With Go arrays/slices, you have to actually check against the length of the array, as you wrote:

```
if i>=0 && i<len(strings) {...}
```

Personally, I've yet to come across a real life situation that requires doing this - in your example, you could use `range(strings)` and stop worrying about indexes.

With maps, which are the Go equivalent of PHP arrays, you can do "isset" by writing:

```
value, isset := map[index]
```

if `index` is present in the map, `value` will be set appropriately and `isset` will be true; if not, `value` will be set to the zero value of the map's type and `isset` will be false.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the issue was more in my thinking of how to write Go rather than the lack of Go's ability to test for an element. I do have "real life" situation where I am doing this, but it's likely because I'm still learning how to correctly write Go

Answer (score 4):

`len()` should return the number of elements of the slice.

> The length of a nil slice, map or channel is 0. (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity)

Answer (score 0):

In `Go`. You can use `len()` function to get length of `slice` in there.

Instead of static numbers `5,6,7 ...`

Like this: `len(strings)`

```
strings := []string{"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"}

    for i := 0; i<len(strings); i++ {
        //you logic here...
    }
```